# Problems using ObjC in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, header-files

At one point, Xcode asked me if I wanted to configure a bridging header, and I said yes, but later deleted the file because I no longer needed the Objective C classes. Now, I need to use an objective c class again so I added the class files and Xcode did not ask me if I wanted to add a bridging header. Additionally, creating it manually did not seem to work.

On a semi-unrelated note, the objective c class I am using is to allow me to create non-fullscreen popover views in an iPhone application, so if someone could tell me how to do this in swift, that would work as a solution as well.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, there were some issues because of bad file references within Xcode. The relative path was one level off, so I was pointing build settings towards `<#ProjectName>/<#ProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h`,
when I should have been pointing it to `<#ProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h`
Interesting that Xcode wasn't prompting me to create it automatically though...

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgot to adjust your build settings for the bridge header you have made.  I had the same issue and followed the link below's process and it seemed to solve my issue.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77

This is what I forgot to do from that process:

> Under Build Settings, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header build setting under Swift Compiler - Code Generation has a path to the header.

Comment: I did this. I tried dragging in the full path as well as the relative path. Neither worked. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You can manually make a bridge file by adding a .h file and calling it what ever then going to `Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Objective-C Bridging Header` and setting it. The .h is nothing more then a bunch of `#include`

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but it didn't work. I would post pictures to show you, but since someone just down voted this question, I can't.